# Improve my function to read and save shapefiles

Tags: r

Dear colleagues of stack overflow,
I'm writing this thread to ask for improvements to my function I wrote in R.
Here is my function:
`

```
reading_all_shapes=function(path,state,type_file,name_layer,dir_save){
  number_files = length(list.files(path =paste0(path,state), all.files = F, recursive = F, full.names = TRUE))/2
  shape_list=list()
  for(i in 1:number_files){
    tryCatch({
      shape_list[[i]] = readOGR(dsn = paste0(path,state,'\\unzipped',i),layer=type_file)
    }, error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})
    
  }
  stacked_layers=do.call(rbind, shape_list)
  writeOGR(stacked_layers, layer = name_layer, dir_save, driver="ESRI Shapefile")
  return(stacked_layers)
}
```

`

path is the path where the shapefiles are saved;

state is the brazilian federative units were those shapefiles exists;

type_file is what type of shapefile I want to read (rural property, permanent protection area, Legal environmental reserve);

name_layer is the name of the aggregated shapefile that will be saved of a specific directory;

dir_save: path where this new shapefile will be saved.

Basically, this function reads several shapefiles that are stored in different folders, stacks them and then saves them in a specific directory.

This line of code exists because inside this specific folder there is other folders (where those shapefiles are stored) and zipfiles of those shapefiles. For example, for the Acre State there is 22 municipalities, so inside Acre's folder there is 22 folders with the shapefiles and also 22 zip files of those shapefiles. That is why i used the length/2.

```
number_files = length(list.files(path =paste0(path,state), all.files = F, recursive = F, full.names = TRUE))/2
```

So my problem is that for specific states, there are a lot of municipalities, therefore a lot of shapefiles and my computer isn't handle all of this process. Is there a way of contouring such problem?

I'm new to programing, but I've read about `lapply` and `sapply` functions but I'm not sure if they work for my specific problem. What I've thought was to find a way to, instead of reading all files, read 10 files, stack them and save, clear R memory, read another 10, stack and save and do that until all files are read and saved and then read all of those stacked shapefiles and stack them together.
But i'm not able to apply this solution in a more generic way. Because I have different States with different number of files so is desirable to have a function that, know how many files are there, so it reads "X" chuncks of files.

Comment: This might be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't know about the overall issue you've mentioned with running out of memory, but I'd highly recommend adding a `pattern` argument to the `list.files()` that matches against either the .zip ending or the containing folder rather than dividing by 2